# How to mock a class' static field using Jest and Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing Typescript that depends on a third party library. The library has a class with a static field. I'm trying to write a unit test that mocks out the library but it never seems to work. Here is a standalone example:

```js
// Library.ts
// this simulates my third party library
export class Library {
    static code: number = -1;
}
```

```js
// Consumer.ts
// This consumes the Library in a trivial way
import { Library } from "./Library";

export function setCode(newCode: number) {
    Library.code = newCode;
}
```

```js
// Consumer.test.ts
// This tests the Consumer
import { Library } from "./Library";

jest.mock("./Library", () => {
    class Library {
        static code: number = -11;
    }

    return { Library };
});

describe("Consumer", () => {
    let consumer: typeof import("./Consumer");

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
        consumer = require("./Consumer");
    });

    it("should set code properly", () => {
        consumer.setCode(3);
        expect(Library.code).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```

In my test, after setting the code to 3, I would expect that the mocked Library is being used and therefore Library.code should also be 3. However, instead it equals -11 as defined in the mock factory. I must be missing something here but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Figured out a solution and that is to use mock variables as such:

```js
// Consumer.test.ts
// This tests the Consumer
import { Library } from "./Library";

const mockLibrary = class {
  static code: number = -11;
};

jest.mock("./Library", () => {
    const Library = mockLibrary;

    return { Library };
});

describe("Consumer", () => {
    let consumer: typeof import("./Consumer");

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
        consumer = require("./Consumer");
    });

    it("should set code properly", () => {
        consumer.setCode(3);
        expect(mockLibrary.code).toEqual(3);
    });
});
```